# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat

Tags: java, maven, apache-commons-csv

I am building an app with Spring Boot that reads a CSV file with Apache Commons CSV.

When I try to run the app I receive the error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat

... I have the next dependency in the pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: it is obvious that the problem is that your code does not have this library, try clean a cache and rebuild your project

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace and provide a [mre].